# I have 12 strings to display automatically in Column N when text changed in column C by using custom formula in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Here I can explain what I want is when Column C has some string or text as shown in below Column N should have associated string for example if

| Column C | Column N |
| --- | --- |
| "New" | "Set" |
| "Invalid" | Left |
| "Login" | "Saved" |
| -------- | -------- |

and so on...

Can anybody pls help about this how to use IF condition with OR operation in custom formula or array formula in google sheet? no script pls

I have tried some logic with searching online but could not find any if any one can help I will appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `what I want is when Column C has some string or text as shown in below Column N should have associated string`. Could you show an example of your input and expected output?

Comment: I mean to say that when I enter text "New" in Column C then without do any thing Column N should get string as "Set" automatically you can pls follow the table as shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do what I think you're trying to do, is to have a range that holds all the 12 pairs (in my case range is P:Q), and use VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP to compare the values and return the corresponding value of the other column:

```
=XLOOKUP(C1,P:P,Q:Q)
```

If you want, you can do it as an Arrayformula from the top of the column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C:C="","",XLOOKUP(C:C,P:P,Q:Q)))
```

[image]

[image]